# Получить HTML-код виджета

Tags: gwt, html, java

Как правильно получить HTML (а лучше SafeHTML) для виджета, не используя `getElement().toString()`?

Comment: чем toString() не угодил? Я видел несколько реализаций разных библиотек где использовался именно он.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> getElement().toString()

Может работать в DevMode, но насколько я помню, в скомпилированном виде это будет возвращать что-то типа [HTML Object]. 
Лучше делать так:

> getElement().getParentElement().getInnerHTML()

Получаем родителя для того, чтобы получить не только inner, но и outer html.

SageHtml получаем так:

> SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant(htmlString)